# Flask Web App on Ubuntu 19.10 Linode, IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app.log'

Tags: python, flask, logging, file-permissions, linode

I'm trying to get logging working on a flask web app on my Ubuntu 19.10 linode server.

logging setup in webApp.wsgi:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.INFO)
```

My first question is will it write to a log file next to init.py The same as on my local machine? Or will it write it into the log folder?

I have checked both log files have permissions 'rw-r--r--' Does the server need specific configuration to be able to write to the log file?

The file structure of my linode server:

```
var
-log
--app.log     <- LOG HERE?
-www
--webApp
---webApp
---webApp.wsgi
----__init.py__
----app.log     <- LOG HERE?
```

The apache2 log:

```
  File "/var/www/webApp/webapp.wsgi", line 5, in <module>, 
    logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.INFO), 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1554, in basicConfig, 
    hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode), 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 920, in __init__, 
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open()), 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 950, in _open, 
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode), 
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app.log',
```

Comment: According to error message you are trying to write app.log to root of your filesystem and user running your script doesn't (fortunately) have permissions to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write full path for your logfile to your handler:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/app.log', level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/app.log', referer: http://xxx.xxx/login

Comment: Your web server (Apache) is running the script. Does it have rights to write to /var/log. By default it doesn't have. Try /var/log/www/app.log instead. Apache is already writing logs to there.

Comment: First I got: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/www/app.log'. So I created the directory and still got: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/www/app.log'

Comment: Where your Apache log is? Try to use the same directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the same error. 

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/apache2/app.log'

Comment: Ok. Could you run `ls -lah` in your Apache log directory and paste result here. We need one or two commands to make magic happen. if there is too many files to paste, select just line where the file you read error message from is mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting 
`root@localhost:/var/log/apache2# ls -lah
total 612K
drwxr-x---  2 root adm    4.0K Apr 26 08:01 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 root syslog 4.0K Apr 26 07:43 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root adm     31K Apr 26 08:41 access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     11 Apr 26 07:58 app.log
-rw-r-----  1 root adm       0 Apr 20 00:45 other_vhosts_access.log`

Comment: And you read your error message what you pasted on the original question from there?  Anyway. Quick 'n dirty (for development, NOT FOR PRODUCTION) fix could be run command `chmod ugo+rw /var/log/apache2/app.log` . That gives writing right or everyone to your log file app.log. When running your software in production your server admin will definetely change that setup.

Comment: Changed the permissions: -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root      0 Apr 26 23:22 app.log. Got the same error IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/apache2/app.log'

Could it be because I manually made this file under the root user?

Comment: Hmm... could Linode using hardened platform somehow. Give it a try to write log to `/tmp/api.log` without creating file first. /tmp should be writeable to everyone.

Comment: Then another option would be change ownership to file to the user which is running Apache process. In Ubuntu it probably is named `www-data`. Command would be `chown www-data /var/log/apache2/api.log`